# Running checkstyle with different JDKs

Tags: ant, checkstyle

Part of our project we have most of our modules developed with java 1.5 but some others were already moved to java 1.6.

The JAVA_HOME points to a java 1.5 version and this is how ant starts with.

To compile our modules with their proper version of java we use fork, executable and compiler settings that are supported by javac ant task.

However when running the checkstyle task it looks like there is no such a “fork” equivalent and the checkstyle will always run with whatever ant starts with (in our case java 1.5). This will cause  some checkstyle errors for some of our classes.

[checkstyle] ...\SomeJavaClass.java:0: Got an exception - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Changing JAVA_HOME to point to java 1.6 fixes the problem when running the checkstyle task for java 1.6 modules, however this is not an option when running Jenkins builds.

Any idea about how to address this? I am sure I am not the first one that I am having this issue, google could not help much.
Thank you in advance. 
Julian

Answer (score 0):

Good question. You could use the *[Java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)* or *[Exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)* Ant tasks to execute checkstyle instead of going through the checkstyle ant task. This way, you can choose the JVM on every execution, and you could even parallelize execution (e.g. by way of ant-contrib's [*ForEach* task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html)). [Here's](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html) how to run checkstyle from the command line.

Also, you can exclude the `.class` files from the checkstyle run. Then maybe it'll stop complaining. Checkstyle does not need class files, as it operates entirely on the Java source.